# Oracle db in Python: missing comma

Tags: python, sql, oracle, cx-oracle

I'm trying to insert into table using Oracle. I'm getting "missing comma" error. What could be wrong?
edit: res is a number value
edit2: I figured it out and changed the code

```
with io.open(path, encoding='utf-8') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=';')
    first = True
    for r in reader:
        if first:
            first = False
            continue
        res = clearNumber(r[4])
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO PHONES(name, phnumber, phnumber_int) VALUES(:name, :phnumber, :phnumber_int)", [r[3], r[4], res])
        conn.commit()
```

Comment: What Oracle driver are you using? Is that the way to pass bind values? I doubt it. Can you insert a single row into PHONES?

Comment: From the documentation, an example: cur.execute("INSERT INTO test (num, data) VALUES (%s, %s)", (42, 'bar'))  - your problem is that your variables are a part of the string, not the  values of the variables.    EDIT: sorry this is postgreSQL - so might not be the same here

Comment: I want to use a placeholder. I've only used SQLite before, and :var is in every example.

Comment: :var is correct, but please provide additional information on the error message you are receiving, what the types of the columns name, phnumber and phnumber_int are and what the values are in r[3], r[4] and res.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use an already existing tool for the job?

- SQL*Loader (Built ~40 years ago)
- External Table (Manipulate a file as a table)
- csv2db (rather new tool, supports multiple RDBMS)
- Elasticsearch Logstash (awesome tool)

## csv2db demo

```
$echo 'drop user csvdata cascade;' | sqlplus -S system/oracle@localhost:1521/XEPDB1

User dropped.

Elapsed: 00:00:01.07
$sqlplus -S system/oracle@localhost:1521/XEPDB1 <<EOF
create user csvdata identified by load default tablespace USERS temporary tablespace TEMP quota unlimited on USERS;
grant create session, resource to csvdata;
EOF

User created.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.06

Grant succeeded.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.01

# https://github.com/csv2db/csv2db
$csv2db generate --file=movies.csv --table=MOVIES | sed 's/1000/4000/' \
| sqlplus -S csvdata/load@localhost:1521/XEPDB1

Table created.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.02
$time csv2db load --user=csvdata --password=load --host=localhost --port=1521 --dbname=XEPDB1 \
       --separator=',' --table=MOVIES --directpath \
       --file=movies.csv

Loading file movies.csv
File loaded.


real    0m3.193s
user    0m1.201s
sys     0m0.422s

$echo 'select count(*) from movies;' | sqlplus -S csvdata/load@localhost:1521/XEPDB1

  COUNT(*)
----------
     76086

Elapsed: 00:00:00.17
```

Best of luck!

Comment: I needed it to be a python program with connection to exact oracle cloud database